# RecycleView item transition to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I am trying to create image move transition from recycle view to fragment. But the problem is that after the transition image is displayed in the new the move animation doesn't happen it just fades in with the rest of the content. What could I be doing wrong. I was following this example:
http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/

I have recycle view item layout with image view:

```
<?xml ...?>
<layout ...>
    <data>
        <variable name="model" type="..."/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        <FrameLayout ...>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" .../>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout ...>
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And then I have a fragment layout to which I want to move the image from recycle view.

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <TextView .../>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's recycle my view onBindViewHolder method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final T object = getItem(position);

    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.model, object);
    holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.getBaseView().findViewById(R.id.logo), "wb_logo");

    holder.getBaseView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, object);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's recycle view item click handler in my main activity

```
@Override
public void onFragmentItemClick(View view, Object object) {
    PreviewFragment fragment = PreviewFragment.newInstance(Object.imageId, "");
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.logo), "wb_logo")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

In my fragment class in which I wan't to animate image I have following setup:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setSharedElementEnterTransition(
            TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    imageView.setTransitionName("wb_logo");
    imageView.setImageResource(...);
}
```

I tried statically adding transitionName attribute to image views but the result was same.

**Edit**
Maybe there is something wrong with my general layout. My fragment container is in a DrawerLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ...>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container" .../>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView .../>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Or fragment class I am using I am using

```
android.app.Fragment
```

instead of

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

within

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: check if you use android version above lollipop and the second issue if you don;'t see the animation on you device could be the fact that animation doesn't work because of the device settings, go to Developer Settings and enable Animation Duration Scale to minimum 1X. In many cases it blockes from viewing animation used in app.

Comment: Version of android I am testing is Nougat and Scale is set to 1x so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was my problem: I had multiple items in recycle view which all had ImageView inside them with android:transitionName="wb_logo".

I somehow missed the point that each shared item in recycle view must have a unique transitionName. when I modified transitionName to include id suffix it started working as intended.

```
android:transitionName="wb_logo_1"

android:transitionName="wb_logo_2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the transition name in xml rather than JAVA side. I think it might not be working because you are setting it when the view is already created.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivItem"
    android:transitionName="wb_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The above would be in your item in your recycler view.

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wb_logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:transitionName="wb_logo" />
```

The above would then be in your fragment

Your start fragment code is correct

Comment: I'v already tried that I wrote that on the last line in my question.